# appcelerator titanium tabgroup order

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am creating an iphone application using appcelerator titanium, I created a tabgroup that has 7 tabs. I want to record the tabs order when the user edits it, and use it as a preference. Is that possible

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. Save the order of the tabs using the [Ti.App.Properties API](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module). That will give you persistent, user based storage of your settings. Then, when your app starts up, add the tabs to your tab group in the order specified by the user.